# how to teleport player correctly for roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

```
function TeleportPlayer(player,toobj)
   print (toobj.Position)
   print(Vector3:new(toobj.Position.X,toobj.Position.Y + 5,toobj.Position.Z))
   local hrp = player.Character.HumanoidRootPart
   hrp.Position = Vector3:new(toobj.Position.X,toobj.Position.Y + 5,toobj.Position.Z)
```

`end`

but when i teleported i fell down instead of to the part
logs:

22:34:39.908  405, 0, -445  -  Server - CoreGame:129

22:34:39.909  0, 405, 5  -  Server - CoreGame:130

Answer (score 0):

When you wrote this:                                                      hrp.Position = Vector3:new(toobj.Position.X,toobj.Position.Y + 5,toobj.Position.Z)    You need to use Cframe, Position is read only.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is correct. Instead of changing the position, you have to change the CFrame instead. And instead of doing Vector3:new, do Vector3.new instead. And instead of indexing the position 1 by 1 just to add 5 studs to the y position, you can just add them instead.

Correction:

```
hrp.CFrame = CFrame.new(toobj.Position + Vector3.new(0, 5, 0))
```